# libxml_disable_entity_loader(false) for error of SoapClient i.e. "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from "

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

This works fine on my WAMP server, but doesn't work on the linux master server!?

```
try{
    $client = new SoapClient('http://mywsdl.com?wsdl');
    $result = $client->function1([
        'code' => '101',

    ]);
    print_r($result);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Gives error:

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from - but works on WAMP

This is very nasty error and many had tried lot to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be caused by the libxml entity loader having been disabled.

Try running libxml_disable_entity_loader(false); before instantiating SoapClient.

So below is the code fix

```
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);

$client = new SoapClient('http://mywsdl.com?wsdl');
$result = $client->function1([
        'code' => '101',
]);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-disable-entity-loader.php

If is called
libxml_disable_entity_loader(true);

, it causes that new SoapClient(.) fails with

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'D:\path/dm_operations.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "D:\path/dm_operations.wsdl

because this wsdl imports a xsd as an another external file.
Tested on php 7.1.12, win x64.